Unstacking table with multiple columns in Power Query
I am trying to convert this table:
ID       rating   cntry   Index
Albert   603      pl      0
Peter    912      at      1
Peter    907      at      2
Albert   608      pl      3
Franz    833      pl      4
Peter    894      at      5
Eddie    753      it      6
Peter    884      at      7
Peter    905      at      8
Joe      787      de      9

to a table with half the number of rows but double the number of columns by "splitting the data".
ID       rating   cntry   Index  ID 2     rating 2 cntry 2 Index 2
Albert   603      pl      0      Peter    912      at      1
Peter    907      at      2      Albert   608      pl      3
Franz    833      pl      4      Peter    894      at      5
Eddie    753      it      6      Peter    884      at      7
Peter    905      at      8      Joe      787      de      9

I tried using Pivot with a helper column but I can only get this approach work with a single column and not with three columns.

Another way.
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.SelectRows( Source, each Number.Mod(_[Index],2)  = 0),
    Custom2 = Table.AddColumn( Custom1, "r", each   Table.SelectRows( Source, (x)=> x[Index]  = [Index]+1) ),
    Custom3 = Custom2,
    #"Expanded r" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom3, "r", {"ID", "rating", "cntry", "Index"}, {"ID2", "rating2", "cntry2", "Index2"})
in
    #"Expanded r"



Love The mandolorian reference!

here is a workaround for you. A little bit complicated.

transform the original table
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("NY65EYAwEMR6cewA81ML44D/6z9ntQyBzjtS4nEMU4ghCd4i5PiZUswuGFYlFhcMqxarC4bViM0Fw2rF7oJhdeJw+U0vThcMbRCXC4aWCp3bCUVM/Pr5Ws4v", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [playerid = _t, rait = _t, countrycode = _t, index = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"index", Int64.Type}}),
Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "group", each Number.RoundUp(([index]+1)/2)),
check_single = Table.AddColumn(Custom1,"check_single",each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(Custom1,(x)=>x[group]=[group])[index])),
Custom2 = Table.AddColumn(check_single,"rank",each List.Count(Table.SelectRows(check_single,(x)=>x[group]=[group] and x[index]>[index])[index])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Custom2, "Custom", each if [check_single] = 1 then 1 else [rank])
in
#"Added Custom"


Then reference the original table to Left and Right tables.
For Left table, select custome =1, for right select custom =0
let
    Source = Table,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Custom] = 1))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


let
    Source = Table,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Custom] = 0))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


merge left and right tables and remove useless columns



let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Left, {"group"}, Right, {"group"}, "Right", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Right" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Right", {"playerid", "rait", "countrycode", "index"}, {"playerid.1", "rait.1", "countrycode.1", "index.1"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Right",{"group", "check_single", "rank", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"



FYI, you don't need a merge.

I also use JoinKind.LeftOuter. but I split the tables into two, and then add index for both sub tables, and then use Index as join key:

let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  numRows = Table.RowCount(Source),
  numRows1 = Number.RoundUp(numRows / 2),
  table1 = Table.FirstN(Source, numRows1),
  AddIndex1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(table1, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  table2 = Table.LastN(Source, numRows - numRows1),
  AddIndex2 = Table.AddIndexColumn(table2, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  joined = Table.NestedJoin(AddIndex1, {"Index"}, AddIndex2, {"Index"}, "joined", JoinKind.FullOuter),
  #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "joined", {"ID", "rating", "cntry", "Index"}, {"ID.1", "rating.1", "cntry.1", "Index.1"})
in
  #"Expanded joined"


FYI, you don't need a merge or index.

Yes, I saw your post and realised that.
